# Angular Material mat-select how can I populate the value from a material table?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

first of all I am a beginner to Angular so it's likely for my code to have issues. Please do consider that while answering the question. I have a Mysql database and a java spring background to use with my Angular front-end application. I took a patient list from my database by using my back-end and put into a material table in Angular no issues is faced until here. However, I want to be able to update the patient info by pressing the update button on the table row. I got my app to take name, age and other stuff except Illness part. I used mat-select inside mat-dialog. Could you help me out about that? I lack of some base knowledge I am aware of that if you can provide the topic and the term to make my research that would be great, so suggestions are quite welcome. Thanks for your time :) Here is my code...

dialog-form-component.ts

```
import { Inject, Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, } from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {Patient} from '../patient';
import { PatientService } from '../services/patient.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-dialog-form',
templateUrl: './dialog-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dialog-form.component.scss'],
providers: [FormBuilder, PatientService]
})

export class DialogFormComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
  private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
  private patientService:PatientService, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : Patient,
  ) { }

    //@Input() dataIlness: string = 'Depresif Bozukluk';
    
    // create the form itself
    patientUpdateForm:FormGroup;
    
    // create a new patient
    patient:Patient = new Patient();
    
    // create ilnnesses
    illnesss:string[] = [
        'Depresif Bozukluk', 
        'Uyum Bozukluğu', 
        'Yaygın Anksiyete Bozukluğu',
        'Panik Bozukluğu',
        'Sosyal Anksiyete Bozukluğu',
        'Özgül Fobi',
        'Travma Sonrası Stres Bozukluğu'
    ];

     
    // initialize the patient form WITH THE VALUES
    createPatientUpdateForm(){
        this.patientUpdateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name:['', Validators.required],
            tc:['', Validators.required],
            phone:['', Validators.required],
            age:['', Validators.required],
            illness:['', Validators.required],

        });
    }

    // when the class called
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // create the form
        this.createPatientUpdateForm();
        //this.patientUpdateForm.controls.illness.setValue('Depresif Bozukluk')
    }

    update(){
        if(this.patientUpdateForm.valid){
        this.patient = Object.assign({}, this.patientUpdateForm.value)
        }

        this.patientService.addPatient(this.patient).subscribe(data=>{
            console.log(data.name + " successfully updated.");
        })      
    }
}
```

dialog-form-component.html

```
<h3> Add a new patient  </h3>

<form  [formGroup]="patientUpdateForm" (ngSubmit)="update()" method="post">
    
    <!-- ### FORM CONTAINER ###  -->
    <mat-form-field appearence="fill"> 
        
        <!-- *** NAME FIELD ***  -->
        <mat-label> Name </mat-label>
        <input matInput id="name" name="name" formControlName="name" value="{{this.data.name}}">
    </mat-form-field>


    <!-- *** TC FIELD ***  -->
    <mat-form-field appearence="fill"> 
        
        <mat-label> TC </mat-label>
        <input matInput id="tc" name="tc" formControlName="tc" value="{{this.data.tc}}">

    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- *** PHONE FIELD ***  -->
    <mat-form-field appearence="fill"> 
        
        <mat-label> Phone Number </mat-label>
        <input matInput id="phone" name="phone" formControlName="phone" value="{{this.data.phone}}">
        
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- *** AGE FIELD ***  -->
    <mat-form-field appearence="fill"> 
        
        <mat-label> Age </mat-label>
        <input matInput id="age" name="age" formControlName="age" value="{{this.data.age}}">
        
    </mat-form-field>

    <!-- *** ILLNESS FIELD  ***  -->
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select</mat-label> 
        <mat-select formControlName="illness" required id="illness" name="illness"> 
                <mat-option *ngFor="let illness of illnesss"  [value]="illness">
                {{illness}}
                </mat-option>

            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>   

    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

patient-table-component.html

```
    <table *ngIf="patients"  mat-table [dataSource]="patients" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{ patient.id }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{patient.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- TC Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="TC">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TC </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{patient.tc}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Phone Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Phone">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{patient.phone}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- AGE Column  -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Age">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age  </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{patient.age}}  </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- ILNESS Column  -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Illness">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Illness  </th> <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient"> {{patient.illness}}  </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="ButtonColumn">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let patient">
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog(patient.id, patient.name, patient.tc, patient.phone, patient.age, patient.illness)">Edit</button>
            <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="deletePatient(patient.id)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

patient-table-component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Patient} from '../patient';
import {PatientService} from '../services/patient.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {DialogFormComponent} from '../dialog-form/dialog-form.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-patient-table',
templateUrl: './patient-table.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./patient-table.component.scss'],
providers: [PatientService, DialogFormComponent, Patient]
})



export class PatientTableComponent implements OnInit {



constructor(
    private patientService:PatientService,
    private dialog:MatDialog,
    private patient: Patient,

) { }

//create patients array to store and list
patients: Patient[]; 


//column names
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'ID', 
    'Name', 
    'TC', 
    'Phone', 
    'Age', 
    'Illness',
    'ButtonColumn'
]

@Input() dataIllness: string;
  
// run when class called
ngOnInit(){
    this.getAllPatients();
}


getAllPatients(){
    // go to patient service, getAllPatients AND
    this.patientService.getAllPatients().subscribe(data=>{
        // assign and put the data to the patients array
        this.patients = data;
    });
}

// debugging method to print name into the console
printId(name){
    this.patients.findIndex(e => e.name === name);
    alert(name);
}

// delete the selected patient via id
deletePatient(id){
    //find the index of the data by using id
    this.patients.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
    //send remove command to the backend
    this.patientService.deletePatient(id).subscribe(data =>{
        // remove the deleted patient from the patient list on the table
        this.patients.splice(this.patients.indexOf(id), 1);
        
        //show new results
        this.getAllPatients();
    });
}

// open a dialog with the given values
openDialog(id, name, tc, phone, age, illness){  
    this.patient.id = id;
    this.patient.name = name;
    this.patient.tc = tc;
    this.patient.phone = phone;
    this.patient.age= age;
    
    // problem: we get a string value but we cannot put that into a select list
    this.patient.illness = this.dataIllness;
    
    this.dataIllness = illness;
    console.log('PatientIlness: ' + this.patient.illness)
    console.log('PatientIlness from database: ' + this.dataIllness)
    this.patients.find(p => p.illness === illness)
    console.log(illness)
    
            
    
    this.dialog.open(DialogFormComponent, {data: this.patient})     
   }    

}
```

patient.ts

```
export class Patient{
id:number;
name:string;
tc:string;
phone:string;
age:number;
illness:string;
}
```

Also I provided a link for those who want to check the whole project.

LINK: https://easyupload.io/yr8wup

Comment: Please provide a working code example as a starting point, for example, an Angular project in https://stackblitz.com/. It's then way easier to help you. Read more about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Edit: Nobody would download and start a project on his local machine.

Comment: Okay thanks for your recommendation. I will try it.